# mysql reinstallation still getting problems ubuntu

Tags: apt, server, package-management, upgrade, mysql

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.4) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting the above erros when I try to install mysql. I tried these steps to install:

1. sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
2. sudo apt-get purge mysql*
3. sudo apt-get autoremove
4. sudo apt-get autoclean
5. sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
6. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
7. sudo apt-get install mysql-server

These step are from [here](https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/)

Is there any step I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

As I see there, you have dependency problems. But, this is the first time you install mysql in that terminal?

After appears that error, introduce in your terminal:
- sudo apt install -f

Comment: its not the first actually. It was running before as well as apache2 but after deleting my `/var/log` everything went nuts